# How to select same Option from multi- drop down several times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a multiple select dropdown with few options for the user to select. Everytime the user selects one of the option it will display the result inside a new div. what I am trying to achieve is when the user selects the same options multiple time I would like to display the same amount results.

For example if user clicks on Dirt 4x times I would except the result to be ( Dirt Dirt Dirt Dirt )

Not Posting any code as it is just the same sample code from the jquery website. see below

https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

```js
$( "select" )
  .change(function() {
   var str = "";
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
    str += $( this ).text() + " ";
  });
  $( "div" ).text( str );
})
.trigger( "change" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="garden" multiple="multiple">
  <option>Flowers</option>
  <option selected="selected">Shrubs</option>
  <option selected="selected">Bushes</option>
  <option>Grass</option>
  <option>Dirt</option>
</select>
<div></div>
```

Comment: `[Link to sample Code]` doesn't really help. We need to actually see your code *in the question*

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan struggling the paste the code in the post for some reason but the sample code is from the jquery website https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `change` event is only fired when the selected option has been changed, you have to use `mousup` event,  here is a working example:

```js
 
$("select").mouseup(function() {
    
    var str = "";
    
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
      str += $( this ).text() + " ";
    });

    $( "div" ).append( str );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="garden" multiple>
  <option>Flowers</option>
  <option>Shrubs</option>
  <option>Trees</option>
  <option>Bushes</option>
  <option>Grass</option>
  <option>Dirt</option>
</select>
<div></div>
```